# fgets() / scanf() do-while loop

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char strA[10];

    int i, j;


    do {

        j = 0;

        memset(&strA,'\0', sizeof(strA));

        printf("Please enter your password: ");
        fgets (strA,10,stdin);

        printf("\n%s\n\n",strA);

        if (strlen(strA) > 8) {
            printf("That password is too long\n");
        }
        else {
            j++;
        }

    } while (j<1);
return 0;
}
```

Hello.  I am running `fgets()` inside a dowhile loop.  I first test to see if an inputted string is too long, and then prompt to enter the string again if the string is too long (by letting the dowhile start over).  The problem is that the carry over from a string that is too long (the extra characters that get cut from `fgets()` being set to 10) gets inputted in the second, third, and so on iteration of the dowhile loop until eventually the remainder of the string satisfies the else statement, and the dowhile terminates.  I need each iteration of the dowhile loop to be a fresh start where a string is manually entered.  Can anyone help?

replace:

```
fgets (strA,10,stdin);
```

with:

```
scanf("%10s", strA);
```

same problem.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Comment: Independend to your issue, it shall be `scanf("%9s", strA);`. The C-"string" always needs one last `char` to store a `'\0'`, the `0`-terminator.

Comment: @alk: Ok.  We discussed this yesterday but people seemed to object to using scanf.  does `fgets (strA,9,stdin);` work, or do you really prefer `scanf()`?

Comment: No, no, I prefer `fgets()` for human input. The latter also takes the **exact** size of the buffer, 10 in this case.

Comment: @alk:  I see what you are referring to... Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
fgets (strA,10,stdin);
int c;                      // Notice that I declared c as int (getchar() returns int)
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) // This will consume all the previous characters left in the buffer
    ;
```

Comment: I thought it might be something like this, that I needed to soak up the additional characters.  I had no idea how to do it though.  Thanks!

Comment: the first `while(getchar() != '\n');`, what's the extra bit for?

Comment: You can use either. But The later one is preferred.

Comment: @alk:  Yes, I had to hide the `while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)` in the if statement.

Comment: On windows for example a new-line could be **two**  characters `"\r\n"`.